# Plex and Nextcloud are not working on FreeNAS

Tags: nas, freenas, plex

I am trying to set up Plex and Nextcloud on my NAS running FreeNAS.

Specs:

- Ryzen 3 2200G
- 2 TB HDD
- 120 GB SSD running as cache
- OS running on a USB drive

I have my Plex content in the folder I want to be separate from my Plex stuff so I can view it on my Nextcloud server and my SMB server. I have set up a mount point as the tutorials say. 
The folder appears as a greyed out file that it can't access.

Nextcloud I feel like I can fix myself.

Answer (score 0):

To have a better view of what can be the problem here, you should add more details.

But the most possible answer at this step is : permission issues.

Is the user running Plex is the same as running Nextcloud ?
If no, you should be sure they both can read/write the mountpoint you're trying to hare between these two

Comment: how do I set witch user is running plex / any plugin